# Convert yearly wide table to weekly long table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with climate data in a pandas DataFrame that is currently in an wide table format where each row represents a year of data for a specific region and the weekly variables are in the column.

Is there a way that I can transform the table such that there is an additional 'week' column and the variable values for each week are listed in the columns?

For instance, my table looks like this currently, where the variable suffix indicates a week number:

| ID | Year | precip1 | precip2 | precip3 | max_temp1 | max_temp2 | max_temp3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1100 | 2000 | 5.3 | 3.0 | 3.1 | 13.3 | 15.3 | 3.1 |
| 1100 | 2001 | 6.6 | 3.2 | 1.1 | 11.3 | 12.3 | 6.1 |
| 5903 | 2000 | 3.4 | 0.5 | 2.1 | 10.3 | 18.3 | 8.1 |
| 5903 | 2001 | 1.7 | 3.8 | 8.1 | 12.3 | 16.3 | 5.1 |

But I want the resulting table to look like this:

| ID | Year | Week | precip | max_temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1100 | 2000 | 1 | 5.3 | 13.3 |
| 1100 | 2000 | 2 | 3.0 | 15.3 |
| 1100 | 2000 | 3 | 3.1 | 3.1 |
| 1100 | 2001 | 1 | 6.6 | 11.3 |
| 1100 | 2001 | 2 | 3.2 | 12.3 |
| 1100 | 2001 | 3 | 1.1 | 6.1 |
| 5903 | 2000 | 1 | 3.4 | 10.3 |
| 5903 | 2000 | 2 | 0.5 | 18.3 |
| 5903 | 2000 | 3 | 2.1 | 8.1 |
| 5903 | 2001 | 1 | 1.7 | 12.3 |
| 5903 | 2001 | 2 | 3.8 | 16.3 |
| 5903 | 2001 | 3 | 8.1 | 5.1 |

I've tried using `pd.melt()` on the entire DataFrame but the resulting table isn't what I am looking for.

Comment: Try `wide_to_long` : ``pd.wide_to_long(df,i=['ID', 'Year'], stubnames=['precip', 'max_temp'], j='Week', suffix=".").reset_index()``

Comment: What @sammywemmy added definitely works! Cleaner option.

Comment: Just tested this. This is 100% what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's name your initial DataFrame as `dfso`. The following code will do exactly what you want using `melt`:

```py
# Unpivot precipitation columns
dfp = dfso[["ID", "Year", "precip1", "precip2", "precip3"]].melt(["ID", "Year"], var_name="Week", value_name="precip")
# Clean the Week column
dfp["Week"] = dfp["Week"].str.replace("precip", "")

# Unpivot max temperature columns
dft = dfso[["ID", "Year", "max_temp1", "max_temp2", "max_temp3"]].melt(["ID", "Year"], var_name="Week", value_name="max_temp")
# Clean the Week column
dft["Week"] = dft["Week"].str.replace("max_temp", "")

# Merge both for desired result
result = dfp.merge(dft, on=["ID", "Year", "Week"], how="inner")
```

**Updated:**

Use `dft["Week"] = dft["Week"].str.replace("max_temp", "")` instead of `dft["Week"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("max_temp", ""))` which is faster (this is the `max_temp` case, but apply for both transformations). Thanks for the comment in the answer @tdy.

Another option (thanks to the comment on the question) could be:

```py
result = pd.wide_to_long(
    dfso,
    i=["ID", "Year"],
    stubnames=["precip", "max_temp"],
    j="Week",
    suffix="."
).reset_index()
```

Comment: note that if there are more than ~100 rows, [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) is much faster than `Series.apply`, i.e., `dfp.Week.replace('precip', ''); dft.Week.replace('max_temp', '')`

Comment: You're right. A slight difference that I encounter is that you need to add `str` before the replace. I updated my solution. Thanks.